# Is this calculus proof I came up with sound?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

We want to prove there every bounded sequence has a converging subsequence. Let $[l,u]$ be the interval to which we know $a_n$ is bounded.Let $\{a_n\}$ be the sequence and  $[l_i,u_i]$ where $i$ is a positivie integer be a sequence of closed intervals such that each of the intervals contains an infinite amount of elements of ${a_n}$ and $[l_n,u_n]$ is always one of the two halfs of the sequence $[l_{n-1},u_{n-1}]$ and $[l_1,u_1]=[l,u]$ Pick a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ called $\{b_n\}$ where $b_n\in[l_n,u_n]$. Then it converges since the sequence $(u-l)\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges, so for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $u_N-l_N<\epsilon$. So if $N'>N$ then the distance from $b_{N'}$ to the midpoint of $[l_N,u_N]$ is less than $\epsilon$ since $B_{N'}\in[l_n,u_N]$.

Comment: The mechanism of the sequence of intervals looks good, but the midpoint of $[l_n,u_n]$ is different for each $n.$ All the $b_n$ for $n>N$ are within $\epsilon$ of the actual limit point, but I think you would need to show that that limit exists and is within $[l_n,u_n].$ The Cauchy-sequence answer seems like a more direct way to finish this off.

Comment: I made a small mistake with the indexes, I think it is ok now. Am I right the proof is fine now as is? Thank you David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1$ we set $l_1=l$, $u_1=u$ and $n_1=1$.

For $i>1$ we consider the interval $[l_{i-1},u_{i-1}]$ and split it into two intervals $\left[l_{i-1},\frac{l_{i-1}+u_{i-1}}{2}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{l_{i-1}+u_{i-1}}{2},u_{i-1}\right]$. Then in at least on of the two intervals there is an infinite number of elements of $\{a_n: n> n_{i-1}\}$. We set $l_i$ and $u_i$ accordingly and choose an index $n_i> n_{i-1}$ such that $a_{n_i}\in[l_i,u_i]$.

In this way we define a sub-sequence $b_i=a_{n_i}$ such that for all $j>i$ we have that $b_i$ and $b_j$ is contained in the interval $[l_i,u_i]$ and we conclude
$$|b_i-b_j| \leq (u_i-l_i) =\frac{u_{i-1}-l_{i-1}}{2} =\ldots = \frac{u-l}{2^{i-1}}.$$

Thus $\{b_i\}$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore converges.

Answer (score 1):

The proof works except for the last line, where there is some mess with the indexes $n,N,N'$. Moreover, why are you taking into account the midpoint of $[l_n,u_n]$? If I'm guessing correctly, you would like to prove that the sequence $(b_n)_n$ converges to $[l_N,b_N]$, but this is false (indeed, your $N$ depends on $\epsilon$).

Since you cannot know exactly to which point $(b_n)_n$ converges to, you cannot prove its convergence using simply the definition.
You should use some convergence criterion.

Finally, you should be more precise in your statement by saying that you are considering sequences of real numbers.

Comment: I should be more precise? I'm no expert, but do intervals like that make sense on complex numbers?

Comment: @Jorge: No, but your statement of the problem in the first sentence could equally apply to complex numbers. So you should say "every bounded sequence _of real numbers_".